# Como atribuir o Name de um componente, sendo que ele não existe no contexto atual

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com um form para cadastro de clientes e dentro desse form existe um `RadioButton` que pergunta se esse cliente necessita de envio de faturas, se a reposta por igual a SIM surgem dois componentes, um `TextBox` e um `DateTimePicker`.

```
if (rdsim.Checked == true)
{
    metroPanel1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]
    {            
       new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
       {
           Name = "txtconta", //aqui adiciono o nome do componente
           Location = new Point(TextBoxX, 15),
           Size = new Size(185, 30)
       },
       new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroDateTime
       {
           Name = "dtpvencimento", //aqui adiciono o nome do componente
           Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom,
           Location = new Point(DateTimeX, 13),
           Size = new Size(124,33)
       },
   });
}
```

Deste modo, quando o usuário clicar no botão Cadastrar devo passar esses dados para o banco, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
Contas contas = new Contas();
contas.Nroconta = txtconta.Text;
contas.Vencimento = dtpvencimento.Text;
```

Mas me retorna o erro de que esses names **não existem no contexto atual**, como posso resolver isso? Há outra forma de atribuir um componente, sem ser pelo seu `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao fazer `Name = "dtpvencimento"`, você apenas está informando um nome para o controle e não criando uma variável para ele. Portanto, não faz sentido você tentar acessar uma variável...

Existem diversas formas de resolver isso, uma delas é criar uma variável e atualizá-la no momento da criação do componente.

```cs
public class Form1
{
    private MetroTextBox txtconta;
    private MetroDateTime dtpvencimento;

    ...

    if (rdsim.Checked == true)
    {
        txtConta = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
        {
            Name = "txtconta", //aqui adiciono o nome do componente
            Location = new Point(TextBoxX, 15),
            Size = new Size(185, 30)
        };

        dtpvencimento = new { }; // ...

        metroPanel1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]
        {            
           txtConta,
           dtpvencimento 
       });
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, será possível acessar os elementos como está fazendo atualmente.

Você pode também deixar os componentes criados em tempo de *design* e apenas mudar a visibilidade dos mesmos. Se todos os componentes deste form estiverem sendo criados em tempo de *design* esta pode ser uma solução melhor que a anterior.

Se você quiser manter o código de criação dos componentes exatamente como está agora, poderá encontrar os controles pelo seu nome, usando o método [**`Find()`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find).

```
Contas contas = new Contas();
var txtconta = Controls.Find("txtconta");
var dtpvencimento = Controls.Find("dtpvencimento");

contas.Nroconta = txtconta.Text;
contas.Vencimento = dtpvencimento.Text;
```

De forma análoga à solução acima, é possível usar o [indexador de `ControlCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.item?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Contas contas = new Contas();
var txtconta = Controls["txtconta"];
var dtpvencimento = Controls["dtpvencimento"];

contas.Nroconta = txtconta.Text;
contas.Vencimento = dtpvencimento.Text;
```

Comment: Entendi era exatamente isso que eu precisava, perfeita resposta. Desconfiava que só atribuir o name daquela forma não era o suficiente mas não sabia como complementar. Acho que criar em tempo de design e mudar a visibilidade não vai ser possível no meu caso, pois pode ter mais de uma conta por cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu criaria um metodo para poder submeter os parametros de controle para criação do componente.

```
Private Sub EnviarFormaPgto(ByRef ucUserControl As UserControl)

            Me.grpDados.Controls.Add(ucUserControl)// grpDados é um GroupBox

            ucUserControl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 7)
            ucUserControl.Name = "UcForma"
            ucUserControl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(465, 85)
            ucUserControl.TabIndex = 2

End Sub
```